# Method from imported class undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to integrate a third party API into my meteor.js app.
So the idea is, when on `/blog` route, the app should call external class' method.

`router.js`:

```
import blog from '../imports/scripts/blog';
FlowRouter('/blog', {
  name: 'blog',
  action: function(params) {
    blog.init(); // here I get the error "init is not a function" (it's undefined)
  }
});
```

`blog.js`:

```
export default class Blog {
  constructor(){
    ...
  }

  init() {
    console.log('init blog api');
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using the latest meteor (1.4.2.3) and the following npm packages in order to enable ES2015:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
"babel-core": "^6.18.2",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.18.0",
"meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.4",
"webpack": "^1.13.3"
```

Am I missing anything in my setup that I cannot call `blog.init()`?

Comment: you need to do `var blog = new Blog();` and then you will have init - `blog.init()`

Comment: You're exporting a class, not an instance of it. You should do `import Blog from '../imports/scripts/blog';` and then `const blog = new Blog();`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this is answered by Yan Mayatskiy and Gothdo in their comments, thanks for that.
In case anyone was looking for the correct answer:

I needed to instantiate the class I imported, like this:

```
import Blog from 'blog';
const blog = new Blog();
blog.init();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you try import class(not class instance). Therefore you can't call methods.

change you blog.js something like:

```
class Blog {
  constructor(){
    ...
  }

  init() {
    console.log('init blog api');
    ...
  }
}
export default new Blog();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a class you need to instantiate it afterwards,  unless is a class with some static methods.

Let's assume this is a "helper" class with only static methods.

```
export class Logger {
    static info(message) {
        console.log(`Info: ${message}`);
    }

    static error(message) {
        console.log(`Error: ${message}`);
    }
}

export default Logger;
```

So you can import it and use it straight away.

```
import Logger from "../../../../utils/Logger";
...
Logger.Info("...");
```